# AWS Glue equivalent of EMRFS role mappings

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

In EMR, you can specify that operations that read/write S3 will assume a different IAM role depending on the S3 URL through EMRFS role mappings.  This is especially useful for a use case of reading from a bucket in the same account, and writing to a bucket in another account -- EMRFS lets you specify to use different roles for read and write operations, and the role can be in a different account.  This simplifies handling permissions when you're writing objects in another account, by [avoiding this scenario](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example4.html)

What's the equivalent for Glue jobs?  It looks like I can only grant a role to the job overall, and I don't see a way to assume different roles for different S3 buckets/prefixes. There are Security Configurations in Glue, as with EMR, but it looks like these only support encryption options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing in Glue.

However, EMRFS role mappings are less important now that S3 supports [assuming object ownership](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/amazon-s3-object-ownership-enables-bucket-owners-to-automatically-assume-ownership-of-objects-uploaded-to-their-buckets/).

The main use for EMRFS was to assume a role in the same account as the bucket owner on write operations, to ensure the objects created are owned by the bucket owner.

Now, you can simply grant cross-account permissions to read/write buckets, with S3 "Object Ownership" configuration set to "bucket owner preferred" and the client setting the "bucket-owner-full-control" ACL for new objects.  The latter can be done through Spark session.

Comment: All a bit messy IAM and such and the with Glue. I.e. not easy to follow.